# FTP server to start when changing runlevel 2 to 5

Tags: debian, daemon, init, init.d, runlevel

I've been searching for this a little while now:

*How do I, when I change from runlevel 2 to runlevel 5, start f.e. proftpd?*

When I go back to runlevel 2, the service should be stopped again.

So
- Start ftp-server when changing from runlevel 2 to 5
- Stop ftp-server when changing back

(Sidenote: the ftp-server is not allowed to boot on startup, so that shouldn't change either)

The closest thing I found was this:

```
# update-rc.d -n <service> start 2 . stop 2 .
```

ofcourse, that's not correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `man update-rc.d` you can see some examples. Here's what
you probably want:

```
update-rc.d proftpd start 80 5 . stop 20 0 1 2 3 4 6 .
```

The 80 and 20 are just to make proftpd start later than most other services.

You may need to remove existing links first with: `update-rc.d -f proftpd remove`.

---

If you have a newer version of the OS, the above may seem to work, but will not
take your options into account. Instead you will need to edit the 
`/etc/init.d/proftpd` file and change the headers there to something like
this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          proftpd
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 3 4 6
# X-Interactive:     false
# Short-Description: proftpd
### END INIT INFO
```

And run `update-rc.d proftpd defaults` instead.

This is because later `update-rc.d` just call `insserv` to do the work, and
all dependencies and start/stop are now worked out automatically, and you
cannot change them.

Check you have the right links with `ls -l /etc/rc*/*proftpd`. Eg output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc0.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc1.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc2.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc3.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc4.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc5.d/S04proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /etc/rc6.d/K01proftpd -> ../init.d/proftpd
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know there was an actual man page on update-rc.d!
I used pretty much the same, did some tweaking to get the best result. Thank you.

Comment: You are lucky it worked, as I tried it again on a raspberry pi and it didn't work anymore. Things have moved on for more recent debians. Sadly the man page is now wrong. I updated my answer for other readers.